# Why does converting to an image to HEIC remove an entire row or column of pixels?

Tags: image, macos, macos-mojave, heic

On macOS (tested on Mojave), converting an image (either a PNG or JPEG) to HEIC results in an image that has either one less row or one less column than the original.

Tried converting the original to HEIC using:

- Preview
- Command line (https://github.com/biodranik/HEIF)

Comment: Your question is very low on detail. How did you convert using Preview? Which line is missing? Did you try different input image sizes and find the output was always a multiple of 4, or 8, or 16?

Comment: On Preview: Selecting Export->HEIF.

Comment: First row, or first column is missing.

Comment: Yes, in does indeed look like the output is trying to make both the height and the width divisible by 4. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Since you're using an open source package found on Github, it would be best if you raised an issue on the author's page.

Comment: Same result using either the Github repo or Preview actually